# ¿Como impedir que el box-shadow de un elemento hijo no se sobreponga a un elemento hermano?

Tags: css, web, box-shadow

Tengo una cuadricula de elementos y cada uno tiene un box-shadow, pero el box shadow de cada elemento hermano se pone sobre el que le sigue (como es normal), lo que quiero hacer es por asi decirlo que mis box-shadow manejen un z-index menor a sus hermanos.

**En esta imagen se puede observar un poco de lo que hablo**

[image: En esta imagen se puede observar un poco de lo que hablo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se como lo tienes diagramado porque no pones codigo pero en este ejemplo, la forma tradicional por asi decirlo las sombras quedan por detras

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card{
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: aqua;
 box-shadow: 30px 30px 10px #00000099;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="card"><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/300/any" alt=""></div>
 <div class="card"><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/300/any" alt=""></div>
 <div class="card"><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/300/any" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

EDITADO:

Pues da lo mismo si usas display grid en un contenedor padre:

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card{
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: aqua;
 box-shadow: 30px 30px 10px #00000099;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 5px;
}
.padre{
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
 <div class="padre">
  <div class="card"><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/300/any" alt=""></div>
  <div class="card"><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/300/any" alt=""></div>
  <div class="card"><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/300/any" alt=""></div>
  <div class="card"><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/300/any" alt=""></div>
  <div class="card"><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/300/any" alt=""></div>
  <div class="card"><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/300/any" alt=""></div>
  <div class="card"><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/300/any" alt=""></div>
  <div class="card"><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/300/any" alt=""></div>
  <div class="card"><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/300/any" alt=""></div>
  <div class="card"><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/300/any" alt=""></div>
  <div class="card"><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/300/any" alt=""></div>
  <div class="card"><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/300/any" alt=""></div>
 </div>
```

Ahi lo tienes, con grid responsive incluida...

Comment: Estoy usando display grid en el elemento padre